# Replace string value using SED command

Tags: linux, shell, sed

my command is

```
sh abc.sh 'hello'
```

Inside my shell script `abc.sh`

```
var1=$1
sed -i "s/'/ /g" $var1
```

but `sed` is not working

Comment: What are you trying to do in `sed`?

Comment: `$var1` is interpreted as the input file name, not the string to process.

Comment: What's wrong with simply `echo $1` if all you want to do is remove the single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

sed wait filename in argument (see  `man sed`)

```
sed [OPTION] .... {script-only-if-no-other-script} [input-file]
```

Into your script, you need to change to:

```
echo "$var1" | sed "s/'/ /g"
```

Comment: You also need to [quote the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Answer (score 0):

You are performing sed on a variable and not a file and so redirect the variable back into sed to get the desired result:

```
sed "s/'//g" <<< "$var1"
```

This avoids the inefficiencies associated with echo "$var1" | sed .....

An alternative to sed in this use case is tr and so:

```
tr -d "'" <<< "$var1"
```

Use -d "'" to pass the character you want to delete from the text.